# error in reportviewer

Tags: vb.net, report

I want to create one report in vb.net.my code is

```
  da = New SqlDataAdapter("select biography  FROM [gholeha].[dbo].[tbl_charachter] where name=N'آیت الله بهجت' ", con)
    da.Fill(ds)
    Dim rep As ReportDataSource
    rep = New ReportDataSource("dts", ds.Tables(0))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rep)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

but then debug i dont view report and i have error :

> the source of the report definition has not been specified.

Comment: take a look at the inner exception. I've found that sometimes the actual message of the exception itself is not that helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Don't you also need a line like 
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = yourreportname.rdlc ?

Comment: i don't want use report that designd with wizard.i want complate report in code.I am sorry for my english.

Comment: Whilst it is theoretically possible to build a rdlc file without using the wizard, it's not a simple task to say the least. Normal practice is to use the wizard to build one or more rdlc files and pass them to the reportviewer in your code as in the line above. If you are trying to dynamically construct a report at runtime I would try to reduce it to something you could build in the wizard and then modify at runtime eg by setting visibility of various elements etc.